# How to split load between master and slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have setup a slave.
For a job that executes a shell script, I configured to run either on the slave and on the master.
If I launch 2 instances of the same job, I observe that the job is run only by the master, and the 2nd instance waits to the 1st one to finish, and it will be run also by the master.

I expect master and slave to work simultaneously.

Why is the slave always idle?

Is there a way to prioritize one slave?

**UPDATE**: In my use case, a job uses the database for destructive tests, so  is not good for reliability to have more than one instance of the same job in a node.  Each node has a copy of the database.

Comment: Did you allow concurrent builds?

Comment: No, because 2 builds cannot be run on the same computer.  But that's the point, thanks.

Comment: I've activated concurrent builds, and it launches two concurrent builds on master, but slave doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an improvement on `Wim` answer:

Go to the job configuration page and check "Execute concurrent builds if necessary". This will allow multiple instances of your job to execute at the same time.

Next, use the [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plug-in](https://plugins.jenkins.io/throttle-concurrents).

In this way, only one execution per node is allowed, and the load is balanced between different nodes.

In this way, a node doesn't loose the ability to run simultaneously several unrelated jobs.

Answer (score 1):

First, go to the job configuration page and check "Execute concurrent builds if necessary". This will allow multiple instances of your job to execute at the same time.

Next, go to the configuration pages of your build nodes (via the link "Build Executor Status" on the main page) and set "# of executors" to 1 for each one (both master and slave) . This will prevent one build node from running multiple jobs at the same time.

The result should be that if you launch 2 instances of the same job, one will execute on the master and one will execute on the slave.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with a jenkins pipeline script:

```
node("master") {
    parallel (
        "masterbuild" : { 
            node ("master") {
                mybuild()
            }
        },
        "slavebuild" : { 
            node ("slave") {
                mybuild() 
            }
        }
    )
}
def mybuild() {
    sh 'echo build on `hostname`'
}
```

Comment: I think this solution will launch every time `mybuild` twice: in master and slave.  It would be desirable to execute just the number of requested times, instead of twice.

Comment: So your requirenments are: 
1. should run concurrently over all nodes 
2. should run sequentally per node

Comment: In each server only 1 instance of the job.  It uses database in a destructive way.
In 2 different servers, it can run simultaneously, as databases are independent.
Of course each job works in a different git branch.